# Simple way to put graphic on the screen in android

Tags: java, android, graphic

I've been looking around for a simple way to put graphic on the screen in android for a while now and I'm really confused.
I've a simple game written in java with swing for graphics and that's all I really need as the graphics doesn't really matter in this project.
Now we want to rewrite it so it works on devices with android and honestly I can't find a simple way to just put a image on the screen.

I'd love to avoid using complex game engine because I just don't need it. All I want is a possibility to draw an image (or 50 images) on x,y given by me and refreshing a screen every 100 milliseconds and I thought I'd be the first thing I'd learn in any android tutorial but well... it's not. Of course I know how to draw an Image with .xml but I need something more automatic - for dozens of images changing all the time.

So what is the best to do this? Isn't there really any way to do it with just some android built in function? If not what engine should I use just for the simplest things I mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple but not necessarily very clean way to do this would be to create an xml layout that is just an empty [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).

Then you could create your images like this:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
image.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT));

//Other setup code for your image goes here

myRelativeLayout.addView(image);
```

This should give you an image of the specified width and height that sits at the origin.

Then you could move the image into position like this:

```
image.setX(IMAGE_X_POS);
image.setY(IMAGE_Y_POS);
```

When to do the moving is up to you as it will depend on when you know the positions that need to be moved to.